# Where is the new GWT DataGrid Widget in GWT-Designer in the new Google Plug-In Release 2.4?

Tags: gwt, datagrid, gwt-designer

I would like to use the new GWT DataGrid Widget present in the new Google Plug-in 2.4 release, but through the GWT-Designer that you receive as part of the Google Plug-in 2.4 release.  Yet, I can't seem to find it in the GWT-Designer palette of widgets.

Has anyone used the new Scrolling DataGrid widget through the GWT-Designer, or can you only create the widget by coding it your self?  I've been googling around, and I seem to see no mention of this.

Would appreciate any info.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional widgets to the designer palette yourself:

In GWT designer:

- Right-click on the palette (preferably in the 'cell widgets' section)
- Select 'add component...'
- Click 'Choose' next to 'Class name'
- Type DataGrid
- Select the correct class and hit 'OK'
- Ensure the 'Cell Widgets' category is selected
- Click 'OK'.

(I've raised a bug with GWT asking for it to be in the palette by default: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=7077)